# Creating a permanente trendline in Pivot Chart for a single chart value

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am trying to create a permanente trendline for only one of the chart values on a pivot chart. I've written a macro for this, but it seems like my if-else statement in my for loop is being ignored.

Here is my code in the Moduel1:

```
Sub AddTrendLine()
Dim mySeriesCol As SeriesCollection

Set mySeriesCol = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Chart.SeriesCollection

For i = 1 To mySeriesCol.Count
    If mySeriesCol(i).Name <> "Actual" & mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Count > 0 Then
        mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Delete
    ElseIf mySeriesCol(i).Name = "Actual" & mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Count = 0 Then
        mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Add
End If
Next
End Sub
```

And here is my code in Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Call AddTrendLine
End Sub
```

Here is what I am getting:

[image: Here is what I am getting]

Here is what I want to see:

[image: Here is what I want to see]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `And` is the logical operator, not `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator) forces string concatenation and is not a logical operator; [`And`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/and-operator) is.

Currently `mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Count > 0` is evaluated, and the result (True/False) is being *concatenated* with `&` to the text "Actual".

So your current code is equivalent to

```
If mySeriesCol(i).Name <> "ActualFalse" '<~ or "ActualTrue"
```

Use `And`.

**EDIT:**

Also problematic: `Set mySeriesCol = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Chart.SeriesCollection`.

You want to work with a specific `ChartObject`.

```
Sheet1.ChartObjects("your chart name").Chart.SeriesCollection
```

or

```
Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection
```

**EDIT 2:**

There's no `Trendlines.Delete` method; it's [`Trendline.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.trendline.delete):

```
mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines(1).Delete
```

Comment: Thank you, now I'm getting another error that says "Run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method" for `Set mySeriesCol = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Chart.SeriesCollection`. What does this mean? I apologize in advance, I am new to VBA.

Comment: I figured that would throw an error. You want to work with a specific `ChartObject`, not the `ChartObjects` collection: `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("yourChartName")`...

Comment: I named my pivot chart "Plan vs Actual", but it keeps saying "the item with the specific name wasn't found". Here's what my code is: `Set mySeriesCol = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Plan vs Actual").Chart.SeriesCollection`. I noticed that the two childs of Model1 is mySeriesCol, Chart1 and i. I tried changing it to `Set mySeriesCol = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Plan vs Actual").Chart1.SeriesCollection` and I still get the same error.

Comment: What does `? ActiveSheet.chartObjects(1).Name` return in the Immediate Window? You can also index into the `ChartObjects` collection.

Comment: I did `? Active Sheet.ChartObjects(1).Name` with a breaking point next to it and it says "method not valid without suitable object".

Comment: `ActiveSheet`  - one word.

Comment: Sorry about that, when I typed it up, it was two words, but when I ran it, I ran it was one word. I still receive the same error.

Comment: Are you working with a chart sheet? If not, make sure the correct sheet is active.

Comment: What do you mean by chart sheet? I have two sheets, which are called Sheet1 and Sheet2, my pivot chart is on Sheet2.

Comment: [Chart sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwyVV.png) - you don't have one then.

Comment: Aren't the examples I posted a chart sheet? https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXE9T.png because that's what I have on Sheet2.

Comment: No, that's an embedded chart on a regular Excel worksheet. Right-click on a tab, and click *Insert* > *Chart* to get a chart sheet.

Comment: I created a chart sheet, but I still get the error "invalid outside procedure"
 when I run  `? ActiveSheet.chartObjects(1).Name`

Comment: I can't repro this. And you don't need a chart sheet, it was just a guess on my part, ignore it. Maybe try `Set mySeriesCol = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection`.

Comment: This worked, but now I have another error that says `mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Delete` doesn't support this property or method. I noticed that item 2 (name: Actual) in mySeriesCol child doesn't have trendline, but it should have the option of a trendline because it is a line graph?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Here is my final solution:

Module:

```
Sub AddTrendLine()
Dim mySeriesCol As SeriesCollection

Set mySeriesCol = Sheet2.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection

For i = 1 To mySeriesCol.Count
    If mySeriesCol(i).Name <> "Actual" And mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Count > 0 Then
    mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines(1).Delete
ElseIf mySeriesCol(i).Name = "Actual" And mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Count = 0 Then
    mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Add
ElseIf mySeriesCol(i).Name = "Actual" And mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines.Count > 1 Then
    mySeriesCol(i).Trendlines(1).Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Call AddTrendLine
End Sub
```